# Solution to unknown function 'v' for a voltage source in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice, simulation, error, voltage-source, function

I have been getting this strange error. Has anyone else experienced this kind of error beforein LTspice?

[image]

Comment: the error is not an error, but a warning, and it says *specifically* what's not right.

Comment: Error on line 6.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common error among beginners. First open up documentation, it will help you a lot:

<kbd>F1</kbd>  LTspice > Circuit Elements > B. ...*,

Then replace the voltage source with a **behavioural voltage source** with an appropriate expression.

The main issue is the `if()` that you're showing in your picture is ill formed.